# In ggplot2, how do I make a faceted plot have min heights and share the same ticks?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'm producing a faceted plot like this:

[image]

This is accomplished with:

```
df = data.frame(val=rnorm(2005), class=c(rep(c('a','b'), 1000), rep('c', 5)))
qplot(val, ..count.., data=df, geom='density', fill=I('black')) +
  opts(strip.text.y = theme_text()) +
  # scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 999, by=50)) +
  facet_grid(class ~ ., scale = "free", space = "free")
```

I intentionally do want the facets to be differently sized (taking up only as much vertical space as necessary) but maintain the same scale.

Now, there are some problems with this plot:

- I'd like to impose a min height on each facet so that you can at least see the right label text and recognize the display as an empty density plot - currently, if I didn't know how I generated this plot, I would never have guessed what that artifact at the bottom was.
- While the facets share the same scale, the y-axes don't share the same grids/ticks. I can force them to share the same grid by uncommenting the commented line, but then I'm manually calculating this - is there some way to just use the coarsest grid among any of the density plots?

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Answer (score 5):

**Edited**

I don't think that this is possible using an elegant parameter of `ggplot`, but will be happy to be proved wrong.

However, here is a workaround that has the desired effect.  The idea is to add an invisible layer to the plot with a single point that is high enough on the y-axis to force each panel to be a minimum size.  In this case I have manually selected this value as 50, but you should be able to create an algorithm that is based on a percentage of maximum count or similar:

```
df = data.frame(val=rnorm(2005), class=c(rep(c('a','b'), 1000), rep('c', 5)))
dg <- data.frame(class=c("a","b","c"), value=rep(50,3))
qplot(val, ..count.., data=df, geom='density', fill=I('black')) +
    opts(strip.text.y = theme_text()) +
    facet_grid(class ~ ., scales="free", space="free") + 
    geom_blank(data=dg, aes(x=0, y=value))
```

**Edit 2** Thanks to @Thierry for the tip to use `geom_blank` rather than `geom_point` with invisible points.

[image]

Comment: I don't want to give the same amount of space to each facet - I want them to take up only as much height as necessary, except for a minimum height.

Comment: Ah, I have misunderstood your original question, sorry.  I have edited my answer to provide a possible workaround.  AFAIK, there isn't a way of doing this directly.

Comment: adrie, you should use geom_blank() here instead of geom_point()

Comment: @Thierry, great suggestion.  Finally I find a real-world use for `geom_blank.  Question edited to reflect this.

Comment: Even better is to use `expand_limits` which uses `geom_blank` internally

Comment: Clever! I'm still wondering about the other point I made regarding the tick marks on the y-axis....  (I'll mark your answer as accepted if I don't get any answers for that, though.)

Comment: `grid.pretty <- function(range) if(diff(range) > 10) seq(0, 350, by=50) else grid::grid.pretty(range)` may be used here to trick ggplot2 in using the same breaks for all y axes; but that's an ugly hack. It would be nice to have two aliases, `grid.pretty.x` and `grid.pretty.y` used internally by ggplot2, which would default to `grid.pretty` but could be overwritten like here.